# PHP: Get absolute path from absolute URL

Tags: php, path, absolute

I have an absolute path of a file, Is there a way to get the file absolute path

```
http://domainname/rootfolder/filename.php
```

and I wanna get something like

/home/domainname/public_html/foldername/filename.php

Comment: Are you sure you haven't confused `rootfolder` and `foldername` in examples?

Comment: how can You at the same time have and don't have absolute path? You should check dirname(), realpath() functions and __FILE__ constant...

Comment: dirname() and realpath requires that the script and path should be in same server but I have on different servers

Comment: zerkms, they are the same things, I mean the foldername or dirname

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [the `parse_url` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the local part of the URL.

Converting that into a file path then requires that you know where the document root of the webserver is. If it is the same server as the one the page is running on, then you can usually get that from [`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

It also depends on there being nothing preventing the URL from not being a direct mapping onto a file system (such as mod_rewrite, mod_alias, URIs being routed through an MVC framework, etc). For example, for a system I'm working on at the moment, if you were to hit *http://example.com/blog/2012/01/01/* then the files involved would be */home/user/recall/script/recall.psgi* and */home/user/recall/root/blog/day.tt* but the DocumentRoot would be */home/user/recall/htdocs/*)

Comment: my script is on different server and the path is of different

Comment: Then you need to know how that server is configured before you can calculate where on its file system a URI resolves to.

Answer (score 22):

This is the easiest way:

```
$path = parse_url('http://domainname/rootfolder/filename.php', PHP_URL_PATH);

//To get the dir, use: dirname($path)

echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $path;
```

That'll print you the full path.

Documentation:

[parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

[DOCUMENT_ROOT](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

[dirname](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

Comment: This does not work for user_dir paths, where /~user/... maps to something inside user's home directory. In that case you have to use `$_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']`and remove the `~user`portion from the url.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REAL_DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should also be checked.  You may also need to check `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`.  It is a bit of a minefield.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. Assuming a URL like

```
http://example.com/subfolder/somefile.html
```

and the file's actual location on the server being

```
/home/sites/example.com/html/subfolder/somefile.html
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

Comment: my script is on different server and the path is of different

Comment: Then you'll need to know what that doc root is. Such data is **NOT** revealed by standard http requests.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/rootfolder/filename.php'
```

this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to work reliably:

```
function get_file_path_from_url( $file_url ){
   return realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . parse_url( $file_url, PHP_URL_PATH ));
}
```