# PHP get absolute path from URL

Tags: php, url, absolute-path, parse-url

I have this URL on localhost: `http://localhost:7777/somesite/sites/default/files/devel-7.x-1.5.zip` and want to get `c:\xampp\htdocs\somesites\default\files\devel-7.x-1.5.zip`.

As mentioned on this question [PHP: Get absolute path from absolute URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242767/php-get-absolute-path-from-absolute-url):

```
 $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
 echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $path;
```

The above snippet should let me get the actual path of the file. Unfortunately this is not working. When printing `$path` it returns the `$url` instead of `somesites\default\files`. Could this be because I'm running it on `localhost:7777`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with server variables:

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$path = parse_url($url);
echo str_replace('/', "\\", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path['host'].$path['path']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be causing because correct url is not being passed to parse_url function. Print the $url value before passing to parse_url function and check if it is printing appropriate value. You might be passing something like this http://http://localhost:7777/http://localhost:7777/somesite/sites/default/files/devel-7.x-1.5.zip in $url because of which when parse_url processes the $url, it returns your original $url.

Hope this helps :)